# Cookie retornando valor duplicado

Tags: c#, json, parâmetros, cookies

Estou salvando em cookie um objeto em formato JSON. Nas propriedades desse objeto tenho links com vários parâmetros. A cada alteração de link, atualizo o cookie com o novo valor. Exemplo do valor que salvo no cookie:

```
{"Url":"https://www.site.com.br? utm_source=parceiro&utm_medium=Banner&utm_campaign=campanha","Valor":"https://www.site.com.br"}
```

Ao acessar a página pela primeira vez, o valor salvo no cookie está correto. Porém, ao atualizar a página o valor aparece da seguinte maneira:

```
{"Url":"https://www.site.com.br?utm_source=parceiro&utm_medium=Banner&utm_medium=Banner&utm_medium=Banner&utm_campaign=campanha&utm_campaign=campanha&utm_campaign=campanha&utm_campaign=campanha","Valor":"https://www.site.com.br"}
```

Os parâmetros aparecem repetidos. A cada atualização o número de parâmetros aumenta. Adicionei logs e verifiquei que o valor nos cookies está correto, ele só aparece com vários parâmetros iguais no momento que retorno o valor salvo dos cookies. Testei utilizando XML em vez de JSON e ocorreu a mesma coisa. Exemplo de criação dos cookies:

```
    public static void SalvarCookie(string nome, string valor, int dias)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[nome];

        if (cookie != null)
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

        cookie = new HttpCookie(nome, valor);

        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(dias);
        cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        cookie.Secure = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
```

Código de converter o objeto para JSON:

```
    public static string ConvertToJson(object valor)
    {
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(valor);
    }
```

Fiz o teste com outras formas de atualização do cookie, mas todos retornam o valor errado. No inspector do Chrome o valor do cookie aparece de maneira correta, o problema aparece apenas no código.

Answer (score 1):

Problema resolvido. O cookie não funciona corretamente com o caractere `&` presente na URL. Funcionou quando substituí por `%26`.